# "dragend" method for marker in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with my marker in Google Maps. This is my code:

```
var map;
var geocoder;
var current;
var styles = [
              {
                stylers: [
                  { hue: "#00c0eb" },
                  { saturation: -10 }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                  { lightness: 100 },
                  { visibility: "simplified" }
                ]
              },{
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "on" }
                ]
              }
            ];
var NewEventMarker;
function changeMarkerPosition(marker, ll) {
    marker.setPosition(ll);
}

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    },
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
  map.setOptions({styles: styles});        
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addNewEvent);
}

function codeAddress() {
      var address = "London";
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/img/markers/user-m.png",
                    new google.maps.Size(32.0, 49.0),
                    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    new google.maps.Point(16.0, 24.0)
                );
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              flat: false,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

  function addNewEvent(event){        
      var NEMlatLng;
      if(NewEventMarker == undefined){
          NewEventMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              draggable: true,
              icon: "/img/markers/marker-add.png",
              position: event.latLng,
              title: "Добавить событие"
          });
      } else {
          changeMarkerPosition(NewEventMarker, event.latLng);
      }       
      google.maps.event.addListener(NewEventMarker,'dragend',function(event) {
        alert(event.latLng);
    });
  }
```

The idea of this code is when user clicks on a map, start work function - addNewEvent, and as you can see, if there is already exists "NewEventMarker", it just moves this marker to a place where user clicks, and if there are no marker, it creates. So if you try my code you can see, that if i click, for example two or three times on a map, marker will moves, but when i drag my marker, starts work function that assigned to 'dragend' event. But it will be works so many times, how much i clicked on a map. How can i fix it?

When i try to add google.maps.event.addListener(NewEventMarker,'dragend'....... to other places in my code i get an error: Cannot read property '_*e3*' of undefined
Please help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evgeny, you did almost everything right but for each click you attach new event handler for `dragend`. Because of that you got several `dragend` events and for each event one alert.

Solution is to just move event handler to `if` statement and add event listener only in case if `NewEventMarker` is created (only first time):

```
function addNewEvent(event){        
    var NEMlatLng;
    if (NewEventMarker == undefined){
        NewEventMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            icon: "marker-add.png",
            position: event.latLng,
            title: "Добавить событие"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(NewEventMarker, 'dragend', function(event) {
            alert(event.latLng);
        });

    } else {
        changeMarkerPosition(NewEventMarker, event.latLng);
    }

}
```